# recognize if file exist with ASIHttprequest from amazon s3

Tags: objective-c, asihttprequest

I'm using this simple http request to download a file from s3 server:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(done:)];

[request setDownloadDestinationPath:dest];
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:pv];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
[request startAsynchronous];
pv.hidden = NO;
[request setFailedBlock:^(void) {
    NSLog(@"Download failed: %@. reason:%@", url, [request.error localizedDescription]);
}];
[request setCompletionBlock:^(void){
    NSString *zipFilePath = dest;
    [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipFilePath toDestination:desti];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:zipFilePath error:NULL];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ההורדה הסתיימה"       message:@"מה ברצונך לעשות" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"חזרה לתפריט" otherButtonTitles:@"נגן אפליקציה",nil];
    [alert show];

}];
```

the download works good but the problem is that the request always succeed, its not failed also if there is no existent file in the request url.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you could check the filesize of the downloaded zip file using NSFileManager

```
- (NSDictionary *)attributesOfItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

Zero bytes would indicate that no file was downloaded.